# How do you pronounce the name 直

Tags: pronunciation, names, pitch-accent

In the given audio https://voca.ro/135zSkjYsgDP the girl is saying もう直ちゃん言い方 to 直ちゃん. It is about the 05:49 mark from 聲の形 if you watch it from the Bluray.

If I understand correctly the ちゃん shouldnt affect anything in this case: [Pitch Accent for Honorifics](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/71942/pitch-accent-for-honorifics).

I can't for the life of me hear whether this is atamadaka or heiban. I can convince myself it is both, so I'm wondering what people with trained ears hear this as. I know the audio is short, sorry about that.

Comment: Compare おじちゃん and あかちゃん [here](https://sakura-paris.org/dict/NHK日本語発音アクセント辞典/suffix/ちゃん) and see which sounds similar.

Comment: @aguijonazo Smart strategy! To me, 赤ちゃん sounds closer, so it's atamadaka? The voice of the little girl is just very high in general so maybe that tripped me up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's atamadaka - sounds like なおちゃん{HLLLL}.